# how to build data pipeline with KafkaStreams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Messages are not getting posted to output topic.

Is there any cluster level configuration is required to use Kafka stream APIs. for information Kafka version is > 0.10.0.0

Comment: There is no need for specific configuration in the cluster. The sample application runs only for 5 secs (with 0.10.0 version) so you should be sure to write messages before starting it. Can you even try with the latest 0.11.0 version ?

Comment: Thanks ppatierno, input topic has many messages and in real time also i posted few messages.  I will try it with 0.11.0 also

Comment: Can you try to read from the input topic using just a Kafka console consumer ? Are you able to receive them ?

Comment: Yes i am able to read all messages using kafka console consumer

Comment: But these messages are not getting recieved by output topic, if run Kafka console consumer for output topic , i can see any message from input topic

Comment: Can you paste the trace for the pipedemo application ? Just to be sure that all the stuff is running fine in the streams application

Comment: Its not proceeding after  
2017-08-16 14:05:42 INFO  AppInfoParser:83 - Kafka version : 0.10.0.0-cp1
2017-08-16 14:05:42 INFO  AppInfoParser:84 - Kafka commitId : 7c67d65755e5b1ab
strart streaming2017-08-16 14:05:42 INFO  KafkaStreams:172 - Started Kafka Stream process
2017-08-16 14:05:42 INFO  StreamThread:215 - Starting stream thread [StreamThread-1]

Comment: Paste your code plz (I know you wrote it's the same, but still....).

Comment: Is this the only trace you see ? It's too few. You should enable the DEBUG level.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I tried same code with kafka 0.11.0 it worked. just added config.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "data_pipe"); to avoid Exception in thread “StreamThread-1” org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to rebalance My real time data streaming pipe line is working. Thanks & Regards, Megha

Comment: Might be related to commit interval setting? -> default is 30 seconds thus it might take 30 seconds until you get any data into the output topic.